# showing the entirety of a collection from a mongodb using a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, docker, mongoose

Am trying to make a simple nodesjs app that shows the entirety of a collection from an existing mongodb database using docker, I have created the nodejs app and dockerized it, I also created a network that includes the containers of both the nodesjs app and the existing mongodb data base. the connection was established successfully but for some reason I don't get any results back.
you will find bellow the code I used to build my simple app  :

The database am trying to connect to is called crawlab_test and the collection am trying to show on the nodejs app is called resultnews.

( When i access http://localhost:5001/ i get a result saying Cannot GET / 
but when i try to access http://localhost:5001/resultnews to show the collection using my nodejs app i get nothing. )

my server.js file :

```
const Resultnews = require("./src/Resultnews.model");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDb = require("./src/connection");
const PORT = 5001;
app.get("/resultnews", async (req, res) => {
  const resultnews = await resultnews.find();
  res.json(resultnews);
});
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
  connectDb().then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDb connected");
  });
});
```

i created a folder called src inside it i created two files :

my Resultnews.model.js :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const resultnewsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  url: String,
  clicks: String,
  task_id: String,
});

const Resultnews = mongoose.model("Resultnews", resultnewsSchema);
module.exports = Resultnews;
```

And my connection.js file :

```
// connection.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./Resultnews.model");
const connection = "mongodb://localhost:27017/crawlab_test";
const connectDb = () => {
  return mongoose.connect(connection, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
};
module.exports = connectDb;
```

Here the Dockerfile i used :

```
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .
#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 5001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

the docker commands i used are on this project are :

docker network create enews 
to create the network,

docker network connect crawlab_mongo_1 
to add the existing mongodb container to my network ,

docker build -f Dockerfile -t mydockerapp . 
to build a container from my nodejs app and finally

docker run -d --net=enews --name mydockerapp -p 5001:5001 mydockerapp 
to run the container and add to my network.

ps : the app works fine when using a local mongodb database so am guessing the problem is from my docker run commands but i cant seem to find it. 
thank you in advance for everyone who might help me with this problem.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: clearly my question is why its not working and not showing the collection on my nodejs app

Comment: Please share the docker run commands that you are using to start nodejs and mongodb containers.

Comment: the docker commands i used are  : docker network create enews to create the network, docker network connect crawlab_mongo_1 to add the existing mongodb container to my network , sudo docker build -f Dockerfile -t mydockerapp . to build a container from my nodejs app 
and finally sudo docker run -d --net=enews --name mydockerapp -p 5001:5001 mydockerapp  to run the container and add to my network

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `const Resultnews = require("./src/Resultnews.model");`

But the result in `app.get()` is `resultnews`.

One is starts with cap and one starts with lower case.

UPDATE:

> When running on Docker for Win or Docker for Mac, you can use the
>   hostname host.docker.internal inside your container to access
>   resources on your host: host.docker.internal:27017
>
> On Linux there seems to be no such feature. However, some workarounds
>   exist, which you can find in this issue:
>   https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264

Check out this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/a0ge2d/accessing_mongodb_from_docker_container/

Comment: the problem isn't with the caps cause i tested the app locally and everything works

Comment: So it's a docker problem then.

Comment: yes sorry but am not trying to access my host resources since the data base am trying to access is running inside an other container called crawlab_mongo_1 inside this mongodb container exists the collection am trying to print on my nodejs app called resultnews.

Comment: Have you check this out then? https://success.docker.com/article/how-can-i-access-mongodb-container-from-another-container

Comment: yes i've tried it before it doesn't seem to work either